# On Persona 1, which is the best way to get demon cards?

Tags: smt-persona

I'm currently playing Shin Megami Tensei Persona on PSP (the remake of the first PSX game) and I read that the way to get the demon cards is to max the Eager of the demon. But how do I do that? My lines can only make them Angry or Happy and sometimes Scared. Are there some lines that are better for this or it's actually just luck?

Comment: I don't know why this was downvoted, I thought could be useful if someone know the tricks to get the demon cards since I couldn't find information about this anywhere. (about the moods and the actions and how the demons answer to them)

Answer (score 0):

Well, after 4 more hours of gameplay and trying a lot I guess it's just luck in the end, because with Mark for example, making him Dance for a lot of demons I could get them Angry, Happy AND Eager too. Even demons with similar characteristics like Foolish or Joyful had different reactions.

Answer (score 0):

There is only really one main way to get them and that is negotiation.

It is a painful system, at some points it is a painful game but that is how all SMT games are. Negotiation can be random at times but it does follow some sort of pattern, i.e. there is a method to the madness.

Here is a full list of the best options for each demon:
http://persona1.wikidot.com/demon

It is a very useful guide, and I would recommend bookmarking it.

Source: I love persona 1, and that guide helped me get every persona.